# What is the callback parameter doing in this program? html5 canvas javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Q1: I am in a multimedia web design class and we are going over images and loading them all at once before drawing any.  This program makes a user function loadImages that takes the sources object and a parameter called callback, then runs some loops to get values, and finally runs callback(images) if there are no more images to load.  Is callback() a built-in function in js?

Q2: Later in the code when loadImages() is called the parameters are sources(which is the simple object with the 2 images sources in it) and the last parameter is function(images), yet images is only defined INSIDE the loadImages function, so what is going on with the images variable in relation to how it is used 1 as a parameter in function() arguement of loadImages, and 2 how it is used to load the actual images with images.darthVader etc.

Thanks for the help.

```
   </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
      function loadImages(sources, callback) {
        var images = {};
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var numImages = 0;
        // get num of sources
        for(var src in sources) {
          numImages++;
        }
        for(var src in sources) {
          images[src] = new Image();
          images[src].onload = function() {
            if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
              callback(images);
            }
          };
          images[src].src = sources[src];
        }
      }
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      var sources = {
        darthVader: 'https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg',
        yoda: 'https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg'
      };

      loadImages(sources, function(images) {
        context.drawImage(images.darthVader, 100, 30, 200, 137);
        context.drawImage(images.yoda, 350, 55, 93, 104);
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>      
Demo
```

Comment: callback() is just referring the the second parameter in the loadImages() method, it will execute whatever function gets passed to it. As for your question about the images variable, you're right, i can't tell why it would work.

Comment: Do you not see the function call ` loadImages(sources, function(images) { ... })` where the second argument is "callback" ? Callbacks are the classic way to run code after an asynchronous method is complete.

Comment: yes epascarello i saw that, what I'm wondering is what is the code of the function(images) that is the 2nd argument of loadImages, as in what does function(images) actually do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Q1 and Q2 are actually related questions. I will do my best to explain them although I am sure someone else will do a better job.

**Q1:** `callback()` is not a built in function in js but rather the function that was passed into `loadImages` like so `loadImages(sources, function(images) {...}`. When `callback(images)` is called you are really calling the function that was passed in: `function(images) {...}`.

**Q2:** The `images` variable you are referencing is the variable set when the code calls `callback(images);` in the `loadImages` function. Both of the names just happen to be the same so that might be what confused you.

Comment: Thank you I think I get it now!  So when it says loadImages(sources, function(images) ... it's saying the 2nd argument of loadImages() is type Function and that function has it's own argument of images?

Comment: @JGoss Yeah exactly. And you can access that function in `loadImages`.